# How to unpackage gems in a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

What is the opposite of $ bundle package vendor/cache?

I want to unpackage the gems. It seems there is something wrong with it, that every time I run `bundle` I get a multi_json-1.0.3 directory in my Rails app.

After running bundle in the command line, at the end it tells me "Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./multi_json-1.0.3".

Comment: What do you mean unpackage? Remove?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that command does is place the gem code inside `vendor/cache`. If you want to remove it just delete the folder for multi_json, it should be easy to find.

Comment: Yes, but everytime I run bundle again, it creates the folder again. Found the solution: http://inancgumus.com/your-bundle-is-complete-it-was-installed-into

Comment: @leonel - Your link has gone dead, making your "answer" unusable. Please don't simply link to an outside resource, but create an answer summarizing the gist.